# Sails-mongodb add criteria in .populate

Tags: sails.js

Newbie here, is there a way to add criteria when using .populate in sails js. Or is it even possible to do so?

Ex.

```
Model.find().populate('toPopulate', {"toPopulate.toFind" : {$in: [1,2,3,4]}}).exec(console.log);
```

Please shed some light

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mdunisch's answer is almost correct, just needed to include @sgress454's fix. So here is the working example on how to add filters in populate.

```
Model.find().populate('toPopulate',
    {where: {id: [1,2,3,4]}}).exec(console.log);
```

OR

you can also do it without `where`

```
Model.find().populate('toPopulate', {id: [1,2,3,4]}).exec(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Model.find().populate('toPopulate',
where: {
    id: [1,2,3,4]
  }
).exec(console.log);
```

Comment: It would be great if you'd include a link to the documentation or something so that the OP can learn to search.

Comment: thanks for the response, but it gives an error in the colon part after where. but thanks anyway.

Comment: The entire `where` clause needs to be wrapped in curly braces; then this should work.